# why is this Jquery function not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

http://jsfiddle.net/bDSW9/

In the Above link When i use with "click" it is working and when i use it with "bind" it is not working .What might be the problem .How can i make it work with bind too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery bind takes a function pointer as the second parameter. You should use

```
$("#imgSaveComment").bind("click",checkParams);
```

because in your example you call the function checkParams and use the return value
to bind to the on click event.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an element with id "imgSaveComment" and you don't need to use () in the function part of .bind

```
.bind("click",checkParams);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bDSW9/5/